# Как сгенерировать звук (tone/noize) в HTML5 Audio?

Tags: javascript, html5, аудио, procedural-generation

В целом я знаю, что это возможно, но на все на что я натыкался - это был обфусцированный код в котором не было ясно как сформировать правильный base64 DataURI.

Подскажите как можно это осуществить. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Составил решение сам из множества разных статей по формату WAV, Генерации звука и прочего, ссылки привел вконце:

### Решение

Скрипт генерирует Синусоидальную, Пилообразную, Треугольную, Прямоугольную волну и шум. Также может перевести из строчной нотации ноты в частоту сигнала.

```js
'use strict';

// Количество семплов в одной секунде
const SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
// Максимальная амплитуда волны
const MAX_AMPLITUDE = 22000;
// PI
const PI = Math.PI;
const PI_2 = PI*2;

/******************************************************************************/

/**
 * Создание буфера данных
 * @param {number} millisecond - длинна буффера в милиссекундах
 * @returns {Int16Array} Подготовленный буффер
 */
function createBuffer(millisecond) {
    let waveBytes = SAMPLE_FREQUENCY * 4 * millisecond / 1000;
    return new Int16Array(new ArrayBuffer(waveBytes));
}

/**
 * Создание объекта Audio с Wave Data переданным в buffer
 * @param   {Int16Array} buffer Буффер в который производится запись
 * @returns {Audio} Объект 'Audio'
 */
function createAudio(buffer) {
    let bufferLen = buffer.length,
        audioData = [],
        fromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++) {
        let b = buffer[i] / MAX_AMPLITUDE * 0x7800;
        audioData.push(fromCharCode(b & 255, (b >> 8) & 255));
    }
    
    return new Audio('data:audio/wav;base64,' + 
        btoa(atob('UklGRti/UABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABA' + 
                  'AIARKwAABCxAgAEABAAZGF0YbS/UAA') +
                    audioData.join('')));
}

/**
 * Синтез тона
 * @param   {Int16Array} buffer Буффер Wave данных
 * @param   {number}     start  Место начала сигнага
 * @param   {number}     length Длинна сигнала
 * @param   {number}     freq   Частота сигнала
 * @param   {number}     volume Громкость сигнала (От 0 до 1)
 * @param   {function}   func   Функция - форма волны
 * @returns {Int16Array} Буффер Wave данных
 */

function synthTone(buffer, start, length, freq, volume, func) {
    start = start * SAMPLE_FREQUENCY * 2;
    length = length * SAMPLE_FREQUENCY * 2;
    freq = freq / SAMPLE_FREQUENCY;
    volume = volume * 32767;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        buffer[start + i] = func(start + i, freq) * volume;
    }
    
    return buffer;
}

/* Форма волны ****************************************************************/

/**
 * Синусоидальная функция волны
 * @param   {number} index     Номер текущего фрейма
 * @param   {number} frequency Частота сигнала
 * @returns {number} Значение сигнала в момент времени
 */
function sin(index, frequency) {
    return Math.sin(PI_2 * frequency * index);
}

/**
 * Пилообразная функция волны
 * @param   {number} index     Номер текущего фрейма
 * @param   {number} frequency Частота сигнала
 * @returns {number} Значение сигнала в момент времени
 */
function saw(index, frequency) { 
    return 2.0 * (index * frequency - 
                Math.floor(index * frequency )) - 1.0;
}

/**
 * Треугольная функция волны
 * @param   {number} index     Номер текущего фрейма
 * @param   {number} frequency Частота сигнала
 * @returns {number} Значение сигнала в момент времени
 */
function triangle(index, frequency) {
    return 2.0 * Math.abs(2.0 * 
            (index * frequency -
            Math.floor(index * frequency + 0.5))) - 1.0;
}

/**
 * Прямоугольная функция волны
 * @param   {number} index     Номер текущего фрейма
 * @param   {number} frequency Частота сигнала
 * @returns {number} Значение сигнала в момент времени
 */
function flat(index, frequency) {
    return (Math.sin(frequency * index ) > 0) ? 1 : -1;
}

/**
 * Функция волны типа "Шум"
 * @returns {number} Значение сигнала в момент времени
 */
function noise() {
    return Math.random();
}

/* Ноты **********************************************************************/

/**
 * Опредиление частоты звучания ноты по ее номеру и октаве
 * @param   {number} key    Номер ноты
 * @param   {number} octave Номер октавы
 * @returns {number} Частота сигнала
 */
function noteToFreq(key, octave) {
    if (!key) return 0;
 return 27.5 * Math.pow(2, (key + octave * 12.0) / 12.0);
}

/**
 * Опредиление частоты звучания ноты по ее строчной записи
 * @param   {string} str Строчная запись ноты
 * @returns {number} Чостота сигнала
 */
function getNote(str) {
    let symb = ['C-', 'C#', 'D-', 'D#', 'E-', 'F-', 
                'F#', 'G-', 'G#', 'A-', 'A#', 'B-'],
        note = symb.indexOf(str.substr(0, 2)),
        octave = parseInt(str.substr(2, 1), 10);
    
    return noteToFreq(note + 1, octave);
}

/******************************************************************************
 *                                  MAIN
******************************************************************************/

function synthAndPlay() {
        // Создаем буффер длинной в 10 сек
    let buffer = createBuffer(10000), 
        // Получаем частоту ноты ДО 3-ей октавы
        note = getNote('C-3'),
        volume = 0.7;  

    // Синтез тона
    synthTone(buffer, 0, 1, note, volume, sin);         // Синусоидальная волна
    synthTone(buffer, 2, 1, note, volume, saw);         // Пилообразная волна
    synthTone(buffer, 4, 1, note, volume, triangle);    // Треугольная волна
    synthTone(buffer, 6, 1, note, volume, flat);        // Прямоугольная волна
    synthTone(buffer, 8, 1, note, volume, noise);       // Шум

    createAudio(buffer).play();
}

//*********************************

let playButton = document.createElement('button');
playButton.innerText = 'Play';
playButton.addEventListener('click', synthAndPlay);
document.body.appendChild(playButton);
```

### Ссылки

- [Sampling (signal processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing))
- [Программный синтезатор](https://habrahabr.ru/post/178915/)
- [Audio File Format Specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/wave.html)

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет использования [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)? Небольшой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/rmedta37

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'sine'; // форма сигнала
oscillator.frequency.value = 500; // частота
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
// oscillator.start(); для запуска
// oscillator.stop(); для завершения
```

Поддержка браузерами: http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio

Comment: Из-за плохой поддержки браузерами.